# C++ Array Characters w/ Structures

Tags: c++

```
 struct prof
 {
string fn;
string ln;
string deg;
string dep;
string pos;
   };


   int main ()
   {
    prof ins[50];
   int i=0;
   int h=0;
   int d=0; 
   int choice;
   a:
   cout<<"Good Day!!"<<endl;

  cout<<"How many college instructor you want to input?";
   cin>>h;




 for(i=0;i<h;i++)
{


cout<<"First name:";
cin>>ins[i].fn;
cout<<"Last name:";
cin>>ins[i].ln;

cout<<"Department:";
cin>>ins[i].dep;

cout<<"Position:";
cin>>ins[i].pos;
cout<<"Degree:";
cin>>ins[i].deg;

 }


cout << "   "<<endl;
cout << "Here are the "<<h<<" college instructor that you encode:"<<endl;
cout << "   "<<endl;


 for(i=0;i<h;i++)

{


cout<<"# "<<i<<" Name: "<<ins[i].fn<<" "<<ins[i].ln<<endl;
cout<<"# "<<i<<" Department: "<<ins[i].dep<<endl;
cout<<"# "<<i<<" Position: "<<ins[i].pos<<endl;
cout<<"# "<<i<<" Degree: "<<ins[i].deg<<endl;
cout<<"                    "<<endl;

getch ();
}

 cout << " Thank you for using this program, do you want to encode again?   Yes(1)          No(2) "<<endl;
cin >> choice;

if (choice==1) {goto a;}
if (choice==2) {return 0;}


}
```

So here's my code. I was asked another version in which it will output according to the professor's department. It will put all "department a" together, put "department b", and so on. Btw, iam new programming environment.

Comment: At first, let me ask what an "array character" is? :D

Comment: i am new here sorry for my mistake, i guess what iam trying to say there is an array element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to sort an array of some struct type.

I would use `stable_sort` from `<algorithm>` passing a `lambda` to sort on departments.